# Where can I find the Railo 3.2.1 installer for Linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, coldfusion-9, ubuntu-10.04, railo

I have been searching for a really long time, trying to find the Railo 3.2.1 installer for Linux (Ubuntu), but all the sources are pointing to getrailo.org, and that website is unaccessible since some weeks ago.
I'm really desperate... Some site from where I can download that Railo version?

Thanks in advance :)
[image]

Comment: This version of Railo is very very old and very out of date, is there a reason to not move to Lucee instead given the Railo project is dead?

Comment: The main reason is that Railo 3.2 install coldfusion 9, and we have a very old platform to support it. If we install other version of railo, and coldfusion, we got a lot of issues and incompatibilities, so we are unable to upgrade the version.

I'm searching this Railo version because I need to configure a new development server, and it should be the same scenario of production one.
Believe me, I'm getting mad trying to configure a Ubuntu 10.04 machine with that railo version, also because ubuntu 10.04 is very old and unsupported, but I really have to do it. :(

Comment: That is fair enough, but I wouldn't think you would get many issues between Railo 3.2 and Lucee 4.5. Sometimes it is worth taking the time to work through some small issues so you can move up to a supported platform. Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Internet Archive, here is the download link to the 64 bit Linux installer for Railo 3.2.1:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120628114447/http://www.getrailo.org/railo/remote/download/3.2.1.000/tomcat/linux/railo-3.2.1.000-pl0-linux-x64-installer.run

I still highly recommend using Lucee instead.

Comment: I'm going to follow your advice! I have installed Railo and works perfect. Thanks a lot!